# How ro recover lost LUKS partition on external harddisk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, luks, gnome-disk-utility

Using [gnome-disk-utility](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gnome-disk-utility), I accidentally removed a LUKS partition on an external hard disk. This hard disk now looks like this:

[image]

I just pressed the minus-sign, thus I guess I just removed the partition but not the data.

Following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) documentation on help.ubuntu.com I used **testdisk** which only found the following:

```
http://www.cgsecurity.org
Disk /dev/sdg - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* Linux                    0   1  1     0 254 63      16002
L HPFS - NTFS          114306 219 26 121601  80 59  117185452
```

Now I wonder, if this [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475053/partition-table-lost-how-to-recover-lost-luks-partition-i-have-some-backup-pa) could help me recovering my partition. But I have no idea what to enter precisely enter into **sfdik**

*Any* help is greatly appreciated as I am kind off desperate since I really need my data back...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is still there, you can look for the LUKS header.

Fire up some hexadecimal editor (in read-only mode !). You better be sure how to use this editor so that not to make any modification.

My recommendation is to use `xxd` on the command line, like

```
sudo xxd /dev/sdg|less
```

and look for **LUKS** string: in less type '/' then 'LUKS' then 'Enter'

then if you find it, note down (on paper ?), the position of the L in LUKS.
Note that the offset is in hexa. Convert it to decimal.

If you have reach this point you have the **start** of your *LUKS partition*, now you need to find the end. You could use the start of sdg2 minus 1.

Then go and use `fdisk` or `sfidsk` to recreate the partition only. **Don't use** parted or gparted that will **reformat** it!

And you should be good.

**Edit**:
I made a [python3 script](https://gist.github.com/solsticedhiver/4ffdd096682eccbb8d389b8a5aa53c33) to look that for you, if you are not familiar with cli.

Either run

```
sudo python3 search-for-luks-headers.py -l 16 /dev/sdg
```

or make a copy of the **first MB** of `/dev/sdg` and use the script as a user on the copy.

Note: with either method, you will find **the offset of the LUKS partition in bytes**. You must translate that **in sectors** to use it with *[s]fdisk*. Your disk most probably uses 512 bytes sector (please check this)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this elaborate answer + the py script. So I found the LUKS Header: `Found LUKS header at offset 32256`, then created partition with `fdisk`. `p` ĺooks like this: `/dev/sdh1            32256 1836339711 1836307456 875,6G 83 Linux|/dev/sdh2       1836339712 1953525163  117185452  55,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
` but for some reason it didn't work. In  `gnome-disks` looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/kK46Ggs Whats's wrong?

Comment: the offset given by the python is in bytes but fdisk use sector (possibly of 512 bytes). So if your disk uses 512 bytes sectors, then the start of the LUKS partition is at 32256/512 = 63. If you find it a good answer, please tick the check mark in the left margin to mark it as an accepted answer. thanks